# Been looking at this js for too long, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code that changes the color of the html table cell depending on the value in the cell (1-6). Previously the code only gave values to numbers 1-5 and it worked perfectly. I added a 6th today and it still assigns the color as if it was a 5.

***facepalm*** any ideas?

the js:

```
$(function() {
    $('tr > td').each(function(index) {
        var scale = [['Green', 1], ['Red', 2], ['Yellow', 3], ['Transparent', 4],  ['Transparent', 5], ['Blue', 6] ];
        var score = $(this).text();
        for (var i = 0; i < scale.length; i++) {
            if (score >= scale[i][1]) {
                $(this).addClass(scale[i][0]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

css:

```
.Green {
background-color: #7bdb78;
color: #7bdb78;
border: 1px solid black;}
.Red {
    background-color: #db7878;
    color: #db7878;
}

.Yellow {
    background-color: #fcff82;
    color: #fcff82;
}
.Blue {
    background-color:#3399FF;
    color: #3399FF;
}


.Transparent {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    }
```

Comment: yeah my guess is you left out the sixth td.

Comment: Please provide your HTML as well.

Comment: Does the fact that 4+5 are both `Transparent` matters? (I can't understand your code or your question)

Comment: seems to work for me. it added all 6 classes. what are you expecting? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdxPgo

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title.

Comment: Your loop doesn't stop when it finds a matching value in the array. So if the text is `3`, it will get `class="Green Red Yellow"`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @MichaelCoker, just went to your codepen, and 6 is transparent and not blue. What are you seeing?

Comment: @Chip oh, you need to re-organize the CSS. this what you're going for?
 http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdxPgo

Comment: Provide a better title and some HTML please.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't see that before. That is probably my issue. It should stop  when it matches.

Comment: Instead of an array, why don't you just use an object that maps numbers to classes: `var scale = {1: 'Green', 2: 'Red', ...};`. Then just use `scale[score]`.

Comment: @MichaelCoker that's it! I was looking to hard at the js and not the css

Comment: Please title your questions in a way that is relevant to the question you are asking. Stack Overflow is a knowledge base and your question (and the answers for it) could help others. But, it is doubtful that someone will search for *"Been looking at this JS for too long. What am I missing?"*

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your question is not clear enough, but still I answer what I understand of your question. I have also modify a bit in your code and I left some comments for you.

I hope that helps.

```js
$('tr > td').each(function(index) {
/*
I would't use 2d array to store both of class name and the ref number, 1d array is enough
*/
/*
var scale = [['Green', 1], ['Red', 2], ['Yellow', 3], ['Transparent', 4],  ['Transparent', 5], ['Blue', 6] ];
*/
  var scale = ['green','red','yellow','transparent','transparent','blue','error'];
  
  // I think that this func is very important to vlid index value 
  function isVlid (){
  var arg    = arguments[0],
      length = scale.length -1;
   return arg < length && arg >= 0 ? arg : length;
  }
  
  
  // you don't need run inner loop to search inside the array 
  var score = parseInt($(this).text());
  $(this).addClass(scale[isVlid(score)]);
  
});
```

```css
/*
It's highly recommended to keep attributes names in lower case as a best practices  
*/

.green {
  background-color: #7bdb78;
  color: #7bdb78;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.red {
  background-color: #db7878;
  color: #db7878;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: #fcff82;
  color: #fcff82;
}

.transparent {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.blue {
  background-color: #3399FF;
  color: #3399FF;
}

.error{
background-color:#ff0000;
color:#ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
<tr>
<td> -2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> -1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 7</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is applying all of the lower-value classes to each node and the `Transparent` class definition is overriding the others.

I think you'd want to loop in reverse order and break out as soon as a class is added:

```js
$(function() {
    $('tr > td').each(function(index) {
        var scale = [['Green', 1], ['Red', 2], ['Yellow', 3], ['Transparent', 4],  ['Transparent', 5], ['Blue', 6] ];
        var score = $(this).text();
        for (var i = scale.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (score >= scale[i][1]) {
                $(this).addClass(scale[i][0]);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.Green {
background-color: #7bdb78;
color: #7bdb78;
border: 1px solid black;}
.Red {
    background-color: #db7878;
    color: #db7878;
}

.Yellow {
    background-color: #fcff82;
    color: #fcff82;
}
.Blue {
    background-color:#3399FF;
    color: #3399FF;
}


.Transparent {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
</tr>
</table>
```